# From which URL I can get com.androidplot.ui.latyou library package to plot graph?

Tags: android, graphics

I'hv been trying to plot graph, by googling somehow I got how to draw a graph in Android but the problem is some external jar files are required to run the program. I searched and got com.androidplot series package but not able to find another jar file containing  com.androidplot.ui.latyou package, can anybody help me out to get this jar file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is usual that a package is named after the domainname of the developer from back to front, so that if I had to release a package it would probably named like *com.herom.blah*, so I guess that you'll able to find your library at

http://androidplot.com

enjoy ;)

**edit:**
even if you type "androidplot" into google it's the first site to show up - was it really that hard to find?

Comment: The package for which I'm searching is com.androidplot.ui.latyou which is not available in tha site Herom right? I searched so many times still unable to download ....

Comment: have you tried to reach the people at http://androidplot.com and ask them directly?
... and you're right, I downloaded the jars and there is no com.androidplot.ui.latyou available, sorry that I took your question wrong.
could you please share the link to the tutorial?? I'd like to play a little with graphs too ;)

Comment: another thing which comes to my mind: have you considered that your **.latyou** could by a typo and it is actually called **.layout** which is available in *com.androidplot.ui* package and does make more sense then *latyou* ?
see here for more: http://androidplot.com/javadoc/0.3d/com/androidplot/ui/layout/package-use.html
and http://androidplot.com/wiki/A_Simple_XYPlot